# SiriKit: Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase

Tags: ios, ios10, info.plist, sirikit

I have uploaded to itunes connect my app that uses sirikit.
I didn't need any special sentence so I didn't add the AppIntentVocabulary.plist

I received an email back saying:

Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSetMessageAttributeIntent in the "en" language

Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForMessagesIntent in the "en" language

Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSendMessageIntent in the "en" language

I've read online that I have to localize the AppIntentVocabulary.plist but I didn't create it. I can't find a solution. Shall I localize to english language the info.plist?

Thanks

Comment: I released the app and it works, but I still receive this error message by email every time I upload a new binary

Comment: Did you ever solve this? All my deliveries (although successful) still give, Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForPhotosIntent in the "en" language

Comment: @Andrea.Ferrando did u solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I had to make sure that the **Target Membership** was correctly set on my **AppIntentVocabulary.plist**. I added my main app as the target (not one of the extensions)

Comment: I added the Intents extension as a target, and it ran fine. Def need the main app as a target, but don't know if including the extension matters.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple documentation, the appStore will give warning if AppIntentVocabulary.plist is not defined.

> NOTE
>
> It is recommended that you always provide a global vocabulary file
>   with your app and use it to specify one or more example phrases for
>   each of your app’s supported intents. Although the global vocabulary
>   file is not required, the App Store issues a warning for apps that
>   declare Siri support but do not include sample phrases for its
>   intents.

Src: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SpecifyingCustomVocabulary.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving a Siri support in your app then you should include the AppIntentVocabulary.plist in .lproj directory present in your app because the app user might select different language of siri other than "en" such as "es_HN" or "es_PA" or else. The AppIntentVocabulary.plist file should be made at project level and also "Localization" of that file should also be done in English from File Inspector region.
Vocabulary Item Example should also be included in AppIntentVocabulary.plist file for particular intents defined.